# AWS lambda monitoring. how to find the culprit function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am a newbie to Cloudwatch, but am wondering how to find the actual lambda function that is causing high invocations/duration/concurrent spike based on my dashboard metrics. we have hundreds of functions, so what's the best way to find the  actual function that is causing this ? 
Thanks

[image: Lambda console]

Comment: You don't know which feature of your app results in the spike? You need at least that info and then see what lambda function is behind that feature that results in spike.

Comment: yes,  well I guess Im trying to figure out which 'feature' that is. like i said. im new to cloudwatch, so I am sure it's just not enough research on my end. back to reading more docs

Comment: Are you saying that these pictures are showing the combined stats for "Across all functions"? To find the culprit, you could use "By function name", filter by Invocations, then just tick each function progressively until you see the one that has spiked. You could also write a some code to extract a Max metric and loop through each function, but ticking the boxes is probably easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the below

1. Go to CloudWatch Console.
2. Click "Metrics" on the left menu
3. Under "All Metrics" tab on right pane, Search for "Lambda" and click it
4. Click on "By Function Name"
5. Type "Invocations" in the search bar near "Graph Search" button and press enter
6. Select the checkbox against all functions displayed and click "Graph Search"

You will be getting a graph with all Lambda functions for the "Invocations" metric and the graph will get you which function is causing higher invocation

Hope this helps!!